# Array of inner subscriptions with rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs, switchmap, mergemap

I'm trying to improve the flattening and reduce the chaining inside my Rxjs code.

A REST call of my service **getAllItems()** returns the following Items[]:

```
[{
  id: 101,
  name: 'Car',
  owner: 1
},
{
  id: 102,
  name: 'Table',
  owner: 2
}]
```

I have another endpoint **getOwnerInfo(id:number)** which provides information based in the "owner" id, information which I want to combine, so the final answer should look like:

```
[{
  id: 101,
  name: 'Car',
  owner: {
    id: 1,
    username: 'Mikelinin',
    name: 'Mikel',
  },
},
{
  id: 102,
  name: 'Table',
  owner: {
    id: 2,
    username: 'Thominin',
    name: 'Thomas',
  },
}]
```

My current implementation .subscribes once to *getAllItems* call and then in the subscription body it iterates per element subscribing to *getOwnerInfo*.

I've been looking through other flattening examples, but basically they "break" the array, and they never put it back together. I need the output to be an array.

I've tried to use *from()*, *concatMap()*, and *mergeMap()* but seems I am unable to combine both requests properly.

Answer (score 0):

The following will use **from** to convert a distinct array of owner ids into a stream of owner ids.  Then it will use **toArray** to convert that stream back into an array and map the items array to an array of items with their respective owner object.

```
this.getAllItems().pipe(
  switchMap(items => {
    const ownerIds = Array.from(new Set(items.map(x => x.owner)));
    return from(ownerIds).pipe(
      concatMap(x => this.getOwnerInfo(x))
      toArray(),
      map(owners => items.map(x => ({ ...x, owner: owners.find(y => y.id === x.owner) })))
    )
  })
)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but at first sight there is 1 thing I dont get.  "Set"s dont have a "find" method, right?, so that would break in "map". I will give it a shoot as soon as I arrive home, I've to get used to this "out" to "in" approach Rxjs loves to do.

Comment: You're right about the set.  I originally had it in Array.from, but when I finished my answer I removed that.  I have fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Map your array of items into an array of observables that each emit the updated item. Then join the array of observables together.

```ts
getAllItems().pipe(
  
  // turn item[] into observable<updatedItem>[]
  map(items => items.map(item => getOwnerInfo(item.id).pipe(
    map(owner => ({...item, owner}))
  ),

  // join observable<updatedItem>[] into updatedItem[]
  switchMap(itemCalls => forkJoin(itemCalls))

).subscribe(console.log);
```

Or you can do the mapping and joining in one step:

```ts
getAllItems().pipe(

  // source item[], do stuff, emit updatedItem[]
  switchMap(items => forkJoin(
    items.map(item => getOwnerInfo(item.id).pipe(
      map(owner => ({...item, owner}))
    ))
  ))
  
).subscribe(console.log);
```